# confused about numpy apply_along_axis 4D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, apply

I noticed a stange bug I am not sure to understand. I have a 4D matrix (samples, height, length, channel) and this function to compute the histograms of each channel (working on pictures)

```
regions.shape #(110, 60, 100, 3)

def GetColorHist(i):
    r = measurements.histogram(i[:,:,0], 20, 220, 10) # histogram of reds
    g = measurements.histogram(i[:,:,1], 20, 220, 10) # histogram of greens
    b = measurements.histogram(i[:,:,2], 20, 220, 10) # histogram of blues
    return(np.dstack((r,g,b)))
```

It works fine when applied on specific samples of the matrix (regions). eg.

```
GetColorHist(regions[70])
> array([[[   0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,    0],
    [   0,    0,  600],
    [   0, 1271, 5400],
    [   3, 4729,    0],
    [5942,    0,    0],
    [  55,    0,    0]]])
```

But I fail to apply it on the **relevant dimension** of the matrix

```
np.apply_along_axis(GetColorHist,0,regions)

<ipython-input-57-246240b60568> in GetColorHist(i)
  1 def GetColorHist(i):
   ----> 2     r = measurements.histogram(i[:,:,0], 20, 220, 10) # histogram of reds
  3     g = measurements.histogram(i[:,:,1], 20, 220, 10) # histogram of greens
  4     b = measurements.histogram(i[:,:,2], 20, 220, 10) # histogram of blues
  5     return(np.dstack((r,g,b)))

 IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I tried several things such as changing my output shape but still got the same mess. Does anyone understand what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Just iterate on the desired axis. applyalong  doesn't do anything extra.

Comment: you mean, with a loop?

Comment: map(GetColorHist,[regions[x] for x in range(regions.shape[0])])

Comment: `apply_along_axis` calls the function along `1`D slices on the provided axies, not `N-1`D slices over all _but_ the provided axis

Answer (score 0):

turns out, an iteration works fine (and quick with a pool.map trick)

```
pool = ThreadPool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) # get the number of CPU

X = pool.map(GetColorHist,[regions[x] for x in range(regions.shape[0])])
X = np.array(X)

pool.close() 
pool.join()
```